# Conversion of CPLEX into R Language

Tags: r, linear-programming, cplex

I am confused on how this actually works. I don't know what the binary means in CPLEX. The problem is:
A manufacturing manager is in charge of minimizing the purchasing
costs (raw materials plus storage costs) of the following four months.
In Table 3.4 can be found the cost of one unit of raw material and the
demand of raw material for each month. Storage costs are equal to 2 e
for each unit stored at the end of the month. Any unit of raw material
purchased at given month can be used to cover the demand of the same
month, or be stored to cover the demand of months to come. At the
beginning of month 1 there is no stock, and there are no minimum
stock requirements for any month.
[image]

For the next four months, the supplier of raw materials has made an
special offer: all units purchased above 200 in any given month will
have a discounts of 2 e. For instance, if a purchase of 350 units is
ordered in month 1, the first 200 units will be sold for 12 e each, and
the following 150 will be sold for 10 e each.
1. Define the decision variables (provide a brief definition of each
set of defined variables), objective function and constraints of a
linear programming model that minimizes total purchasing costs

Solution:
[image]

CPLEX code

```
Minimize
cost : 12 q1 + 14 q2 + 16 q3 + 18 q4 + 10 r1 + 12 r2 + 14 r3 + 16
          r4 + 2 s1 + 2 s2 + 2 s3 + 2 s4
Subject To
  d1 : q1 + r1 - s1 = 150
  d2 : s1 + q2 + r2 - s2 = 200
  d3 : s2 + q3 + r3 - s3 = 250
  d4 : s3 + q4 + r4 - s4 = 150
  l1 : q1 - 200 b1 >= 0
  l2 : q2 - 200 b2 >= 0
  l3 : q3 - 200 b3 >= 0
  l4 : q4 - 200 b4 >= 0
  m1 : r1 - 10000 b1 <= 0
  m2 : r2 - 10000 b2 <= 0
  m3 : r3 - 10000 b3 <= 0
  m4 : r4 - 10000 b4 <= 0
Bounds
  0 <= q1 <= 200
  0 <= q2 <= 200
  0 <= q3 <= 200
  0 <= q4 <= 200
Binary
  b1
  b2
  b3
  b4
End
```

My code:

```
library ( lpSolve )
#defining parameters
obj.fun <- c(12 , 14, 16, 18, 10, 12, 14, 2, 2, 2, 2)
constr <- matrix (c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0,1,0,0,1,-1,0,0,
        0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,-1,0
        0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,-1) , ncol = 4 , byrow =TRUE )
constr.dir <- c("=","=", "=", "=")
rhs <- c(150 , 200 , 250, 150)
#solving model
prod.sol <- lp ("max", obj.fun , constr , constr.dir , rhs ,compute.sens = TRUE)
#accessing to R output
prod.sol$obj.val 
prod.sol$solution 
prod.sol$duals 
#sensibility analysis results
prod.sol$duals.from
prod.sol$duals.to
prod.sol$sens.coef.from
prod.sol$sens.coef.to
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary means that b1,b2,b3,b4 are either 0 or 1, so if b1 == 1 and you have 10000 b1, it means that you buy 10000 * 1 = 10000 pieces of raw material in the first month, and from the solution you wont buy any raw materials in months 2,3 or 4

in english, a binary variable is used to express variables that are either completely off, or completely on

As the solution states "the best option is to purchase all units on month 1"

And how do you create that constraint? You do it using binary variables

Your teacher is prepping you to learn mixed-integer programming, which relies in part on binary variables

depending on the cplex wrapper you're using see

[cplexAPI](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cplexAPI/cplexAPI.pdf) or [Rcplex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcplex/Rcplex.pdf), and search for binary variables